# Double Condition Merge using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge the following tables using the `pandas` library in python. I have tried to do this with variation of `merge_as_of` and `merge` with no success.

Master Data:

| Asset ID | Size (mm) | Depth (m) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 400 | 1 |
| 3 | 500 | 4.5 |

Condition Table:

| < Size (mm) | < Depth (m) | Estimated Repair Time (days) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 300 | 4 | 1.5 |
| 300 | 6 | 2 |
| 600 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 600 | 4 | 2 |
| 600 | 6 | 3 |

To achieve the following table:

| Asset ID | Size (mm) | Depth (m) | Estimated Repair Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 1.5 | 1 |
| 2 | 400 | 1 | 1.5 |
| 3 | 400 | 4.5 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `pd.cut` to genarate a range label of size and Depth.

then join the two table with range labels.

```
# create label with pd.cut
# Index(['< Size (mm)', '< Depth (m)', 'Estimated Repair Time (days)'], dtype='object')
dfa['Size'] = pd.cut(dfa['< Size (mm)'], bins = [0, 300, 600])
dfa['Depth'] = pd.cut(dfa['< Depth (m)'], bins = [0, 2, 4, 6])

dfm['Size'] = pd.cut(dfm['Size (mm)'], bins = [0, 300, 600])
dfm['Depth'] = pd.cut(dfm['Depth (m)'], bins = [0, 2, 4, 6])

df = dfm.join(dfa.set_index(['Size', 'Depth'])['Estimated Repair Time (days)'],
         on=['Size', 'Depth'])
print(df)

       Asset ID  Size (mm)  Depth (m)        Size   Depth  \
    0         1        100        1.5    (0, 300]  (0, 2]   
    1         2        400        1.0  (300, 600]  (0, 2]   
    2         3        500        4.5  (300, 600]  (4, 6]   

       Estimated Repair Time (days)  
    0                           1.0  
    1                           1.5  
    2                           3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do the same way a relational engine would do it

1. do a Cartesian product
2. apply filter conditions
3. select unique

```
dfm = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Asset ID   Size (mm)   Depth (m)
1   100 1.5
2   400 1
3   500 4.5
"""),sep="\t")

dfa = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""< Size (mm)    < Depth (m) Estimated Repair Time (days)
300 2   1
300 4   1.5
300 6   2
600 2   1.5
600 4   2
600 6   3
"""), sep="\t")

dfraw = dfm.assign(foo=1).merge(dfa.assign(foo=1), on="foo", how="left")
dffinal = (dfraw.loc[dfraw["Size (mm)"].lt(dfraw["< Size (mm)"]) & dfraw["Depth (m)"].lt(dfraw["< Depth (m)"])]
 .groupby("Asset ID", as_index=False).first()
)
```

|  | Asset ID | Size (mm) | Depth (m) | foo | < Size (mm) | < Depth (m) | Estimated Repair Time (days) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 100 | 1.5 | 1 | 300 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 400 | 1 | 1 | 600 | 2 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 3 | 500 | 4.5 | 1 | 600 | 6 | 3 |